# Fastest of the following Mapping objects (Dictionary,Tuple,KeyvaluePair)

Tags: c#, optimization, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap

Currently i have a mapping setup like this

```
//Identifiers to save (currently)
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> toSaveIdentifiers =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(); //
```

however, i want to add an extra dimension to it because i just missed out on an extra attribute to add.

I'm trying to set up some form of mapping that gets populated frequently in a program and is looked up throughout the program as well. I was wondering what is the best way to go about doing this.

```
//Identifiers to save (tuple)
Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>, Dictionary<string, string>> toSaveIdentifiers =
    new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Dictionary<string, string>>(); //

//Identifiers to save (adding another dictionary dimension)
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>> toSaveIdentifiers =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(); //

//Identifiers to save (adding keyvaluepair)
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string,string>, Dictionary<string, string>> toSaveIdentifiers =
    new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, Dictionary<string, string>>(); //
```

When i populate it/lookup i do something like.

```
   // check identifier map dictionary
    if (dictionary.Keys.Contains(identifier))
    {
        if (dictionary[identifier].Keys.Contains(currency))
        {
            //stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
    else
    {
            //more stuff
    }
```

What would be the best method of doing this for lookup?

Comment: Please learn [`How to Write Good Title?`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: You should definitely create your own, custom `class`/`struct` with meaningful property names instead of `Dictionary`, `Tuple`, `KeyValuePair` and any combination of these.

Comment: Somewhere in the maze of that hierarchy of nested generic collections, maybe a self-documenting class wouldn't have proven to be more useful?

Comment: 100% agree with @MarcinJuraszek, when you have these kind of endless sequences of nested Dictionaries / Tuples / etc. it's almost always a sign of a poor data model.

Comment: Agreed ... the time spend doing that now will more than payoff when you or others go back to maintain this code in the future.

Comment: thanks guys that is one of my options, but im asking in general which would be better of these if i couldn't create a new class for it

Comment: @Ramie None of them! It's better not to code at all than code in style like that one ...

Comment: I went through this with our code base. We have a type `CompoundDictionary<TK1, TK2, TK3, TVal>` that inherits `Dictionary<TK1, Dictionary<TK2, Dictionary<TK3, TVal>>>` with supporting code (such as full-key indexers) and this is **far and away faster** than the same implementation using manual compound keys via a `class` or `struct`. The only downside is that all the keys making a compound element must be non-null, whereas a custom type used as a key could have null parts so long as the type instance itself wasn't null. I'm *not* saying it's the most suitable, however.

Comment: Also, if you use a `struct`, remember to provide a custom `GetHashCode` implementation, otherwise again performance suffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your identifiers all seem to be of type string, you could always just concat them all into one big string and use that as the key. Then instead of doing the nested Contains, you'd just have to do one.  It'd also be more flexible as far a storing different levels of identifiers.

i.e. Given a 2 level key, it'd be

```
string ident = level1Identifier + "." + level2Identifier;
```

(using string.format() or StringBuilder would be more efficient, but this code is better for explaining)

Also consider the joining character should be something you know won't show up in any levels identifier to avoid confusion or accidently duplicates.